# Crontabs does not write to a location (permissions?)

Tags: cron

I have crontabs set up to download data published on a webpage and save it locally every x seconds:

```
* * * * * sleep 0; wget -O /home/lab/Documents/watchdog.xml 'IP-address'
```

and this works!

I actually want to save the file somewhere else, so if I try:

```
 * * * * * sleep 0; wget -O /var/cache/watchdog.xml 'IP-address'
```

it does not work.

Since changing the location of the target file solves the issue, I'm assuming it's a permission issue? How do I check/change permissions for `crontabs`?

Comment: Are you setting this in `crontab -e`? What permissions does your user have on `/var/cache/`?

Comment: BTW: What's with the `sleep 0`?

Comment: ahhhh....have you tried to run the command sequence outside of cron to make sure it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User crontabs (that you edit by running `crontab -e`) run as your user — so they use your user's permissions.

So you need to make the file writable as your user; most likely `sudo chown "$USER" /var/cache/watchdog.xml` would do that, if the file already exists. (If not, `sudo touch /var/cache/watchdog.xml` will create an empty file there). There are other ways (e.g., by changing the group and making it group-writable, or by using ACLs); which makes the most sense depends on the situation.

Alternatively, you can use a system crontab (configured by editing `/etc/crontab` with a text editor, or—preferably if your system has it—creating a file in `/etc/cron.d`) which can run as any user. Note that system crontabs add an extra field: the user to run the command as. It comes between the day-of-week field and the command field.